Azure DevOps Pipeline to set the variable for recordId
I'm trying to set the variable for recordId which I'm using different stages but unable get the newRecordId , on  stage tfvalidate, printing id as null Record ID:

PUT Response: {"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}.

Stage updatestatus is working as expected Please let me know if I missed something, assist me to resolve this issue.
trigger: none
#########################
# Declare Build Agents:-
#########################
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
######################
#DECLARE PARAMETERS:-
######################
parameters:
- name: TicketNumber
  displayName: Please Provide the Number:-
  type: object
  
###################
# Declare Stages:-
###################
stages:
- stage: UpdateStatus
  jobs:
      - job: UpdateTriggeredStatus
        steps:
          - script: |
              # Send "triggered" status to the API endpoint
              response=$(curl -s -X GET "http://amazonaws.com:800/ticket_details/?TicketNumber=${{ parameters.TicketNumber }}")
              
              # Extract the record ID and other details from the response
              record=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.data[] | select(.TicketNumber == "'${{ parameters.TicketNumber }}'")')
              recordId=$(echo "$record" | jq -r '._id')
              echo "Record ID: $recordId"
              # Set the recordId as a pipeline variable
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=recordId;isOutput=true]$recordId"
              
            
              # Validate that the record was found
              if [ -z "$recordId" ]; then
                echo "No record found for TicketNumber: ${{ parameters.TicketNumber }}"
                exit 1
              fi

              # Send "triggered" status to the API endpoint using PUT request
              echo "Updating record with ID: $recordId"
              putResponse=$(curl -s -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
                "TicketNumber": "${{ parameters.TicketNumber }}",
                "TicketSysID": "${{ parameters.TicketSysID }}",
                "Status": "Triggered",
                "Logs": "NA"
              }' "http://.compute.amazonaws.com:800/ticket_details/$recordId")
              echo "PUT Response: $putResponse"

              # Extract the "message" field from the JSON response
              message=$(echo "$putResponse" | jq -r '.message')

              if [[ "$message" == "Data name updated successfully" ]]; then
                echo "Status update to triggered was successful!"
              else
                echo "Status update to triggered failed with message: $message"
                exit 1
              fi

              # Print the full response for debugging
              echo "Response: $putResponse"
              # Set the recordId as a pipeline variable
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=recordId;isOutput=true]$recordId"
            displayName: 'Fetch, Update and Validate Record'  
- stage: tfvalidate
  dependsOn: UpdateStatus
  jobs:
    - job: validate
      variables: 
        - group: AzureDevopsCred
        - name: newRecordId
          value: $[ stageDependencies.UpdateStatus.UpdateTriggeredStatus.outputs['UpdateTriggeredStatusJob.recordId'] ]
                 
      continueOnError: false
      steps:
        - task: TerraformInstaller@0
          inputs:
            terraformVersion: 'latest'
 
        - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
          displayName: init
          inputs:
            provider: 'azurerm'
            command: 'init'
            workingDirectory: 'LaunchStack/terraform/azure/testmarklogic'
            backendServiceArm: 'OIDC_TEST'
            backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
            backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: $(StorageAccount)
            backendAzureRmContainerName: $(Container)
            backendAzureRmKey: $(TfstateFile)
        
        - script: | 
            echo "Record ID: $(newRecordId)"
            putResponse=$(curl -s -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
              "TicketNumber": "${{ parameters.TicketNumber }}",
              "TicketSysID": "${{ parameters.TicketSysID }}",
              "Status": "Executing",
              "Logs": "NA"
            }' "http://amazonaws.com:800/ticket_details/$(newRecordId)")
            echo "PUT Response: $putResponse"
          displayName: 'Update Record Status to Executing'          


Hi @User, As RUI suggested in the answer below, you need to first add name property for the script task where the output variable recordId is generated, so that it can be referenced in downstream stage/job/task. Please let us know if it works to resolve the issue in this post. Thx.

Did any of the below answers help you solve your problem?

Dependencies should use step names. Check examples here: Set an output variable for use in future jobs, Dependency syntax overview.
Add the name property to the first script and use it in the reference.
    - name: newRecordId
      value: $[ stageDependencies.UpdateStatus.UpdateTriggeredStatus.outputs['Step1.recordId'] ]


To use the output variable from a different stage, the format for referencing variables is the following:
stageDependencies.STAGE.JOB.outputs['TASK.VARIABLE']

The first thing to do is to set the name of the task where the output variable is being set:
- job: UpdateTriggeredStatus
  steps:
    - script: |
        # other commands here 
        
        # Set the recordId as a pipeline variable
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=recordId;isOutput=true]$recordId"
      displayName: 'Fetch, Update and Validate Record'
      name: SetRecordIdTask # <--------------- set task name

And then fix the reference to the output variable, according to the syntax mentioned above:
- name: newRecordId
  value: $[ stageDependencies.UpdateStatus.UpdateTriggeredStatus.outputs['SetRecordIdTask.recordId'] ]

